# Seaching Nodes depending on distance each nodes

Tags: python, math, networkx, geopandas, osmnx

I search for Nodes in Shibuya, Tokyo by OSMNX, Python.
In my case,　I want to find the nodes depending on each distance.
I want to search 2 cases, distances between the nodes under 30m and over 100m, and show the usual nodes list.
I tried to make scripts but I can't show...
I think I made a mistake in simple coding. Could you tell me?
Thank!

This is my scripts.

```
import osmnx as ox
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import networkx as nx
from colorspacious import cspace_converter

ward_names = [
    "Shibuya",
]

graph = ox.graph_from_place(ward_names, network_type="drive")

nodes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph, nodes=True, edges=False)
edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph, nodes=False, edges=True)

print("Number of nodes:", len(nodes))
print("Number of edges:", len(edges))
ox.plot_graph(graph)

gdf_nodes, gdf_edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph)

# Find nodes that are separated by a distance of less than 30 meters and lead to 4 edges
# s_cross = Small crossing

s_cross = []
for node in graph.nodes():
    if len(list(graph.neighbors(node))) == 4:
        # distance
        distances = nx.shortest_path_length(graph, node)
        if max(distances.values()) <= 30:
            s_cross.append(node)
s_cross


# Find nodes that are separated by a distance of more than 100 meters and lead to 4 edges
# b_cross = Big crossing

b_cross = []
for node in graph.nodes():
    if len(list(graph.neighbors(node))) == 4:
        # distance
        distances = nx.shortest_path_length(graph, node)
        if max(distances.values()) >= 100:
            b_cross.append(node)
b_cross
```

Comment: I don't understand your `b_cross` nodes; the selection criterion seems wrong to me. Surely, for every crossing, there exist some other crossing that is more than 100 meters away. Could it be that you are actually looking for the minimum there, i.e. find crossings for which the nearest crossing is more than 100 meters away?

Comment: @PaulBrodersen Thanks comment! Yes! b_cross, I want to find the distance between crossings(nodes) is more than (at least) 100m.

Comment: Are small crossings/4-way intersections small because a) the nearest node in the graph is less than 30 m away, or because b) the next crossing is less than 30 m away?

Comment: Yes, S crossing, distance of each nodes is less than 30m away.